# Can I get science from asteroids?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Wow, I've just noticed a load of asteroids appearing in KSP's space center. My first thought isn't "What if they hit Kerbin and wipe out the entire Kerbal race?". It's "How much science can I get from them?"

Can I get science from asteroids?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes, you can!

Just like any other experiment part (since [Asteroids](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Asteroid), too, are just parts), you can dock with the Asteroid using [the Claw](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Advanced_Grabbing_Unit) and then take a sample of it.

[Just like other experiments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163208/what-science-can-i-perform-on-and-near-kerbin/163209#163209), the result depends on the current location of your craft (altitude, sphere of influence, orbital parameters) with each such situation *for each asteroid individually* (unlike other experiments) yielding *60 Science*.

Comment: So you're saying I should land my asteroid on Minmus, and roll it around to different biomes to gain massive science?

Comment: @MBraedley Basically, yes. I haven't tested it on non-Kerbin bodies, but afaik that should work as well.

Comment: @MBraedley: That would seem to perfectly capture the essence of Kerbal science.